# ListView Items Deselected When Scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm having the problem where when selected items and I start scrolling they are being deselected, ive seen a few other posts about this some of them said to put into a Array and such but I have tried a few none seem to be working.

My Code:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Product> objects;


ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

   final Product p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

    final CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
    SharedPreferences settings  = ctx.getSharedPreferences("data",ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean Checked = settings.getBoolean(p.name, false);
    cbBuy.setChecked(Checked);



    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(cbBuy.isChecked()==true){
                SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                settings.edit().putBoolean(p.name, true).commit();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "You Selected" + p.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }else{
                SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                settings.edit().putBoolean(p.name, false).commit();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "You Deselected" +p.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });{

        return view;

    }

}

Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
}

ArrayList<Product> getBox() {
    ArrayList<Product> box = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product p : objects) {
        if (p.box)
            box.add(p);
    }
    return box;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {

        getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;

    }


};
}
```

Product Class:

```
public class Product {
String name;
String price;
int image;
boolean isSelected = false;

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected)
{
    isSelected = selected;
}


Product(String _describe, String _price, int _image, boolean _box) {
    name = _describe;
    price = _price;
    image = _image;
    isSelected = _box;
}


}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
ListAdapter boxAdapter;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private String mData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    fillData();
    boxAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, products);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);

}

void fillData() {
    products.add(new Product("Al", "5230%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Al", "5230%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Alf", "5230%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Alfa", "5230%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Alfae", "5120%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Alfsdfsdfakher", "50435%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Alfasdfsdfkher", "5123120%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Alfasdfsdfkher", "501231%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    products.add(new Product("Alfaksdfsdfher", "11250%", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    /*for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        products.add(new Product("Product " + i, i * 100,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
    }*/
}

/*public void showResult(View v) {
    String result = "Selected Product are :";
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.box){
            result += "\n" + p.name;
            totalAmount+=p.price;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}*/
}
```

Comment: You should use a ListView holder pattern. Something like that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730417/making-a-listview-holder-for-mainactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can manage one variable in model class
Like this

```
public class Product
{
      private boolean isSelected=false;

      //Make ur getter and settter
}
```

Adapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

   final Product p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

    final CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
    SharedPreferences settings  = ctx.getSharedPreferences("data",ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean Checked = settings.getBoolean(p.name, false);
    cbBuy.setChecked(Checked);

//use click listener instead of checked change
cbBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(objects.get(position).isSelected)
       {
              cbBuy.setChecked(false);
              objects.get(position).setSelected(false);

 //Save into sharepref here
 SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                settings.edit().putBoolean(p.name, false).commit();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "You Selected" + p.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
       else
       {
              cbBuy.setChecked(true);
              objects.get(position).setSelected(true);

//Save into sharepref here
  SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                settings.edit().putBoolean(p.name, true).commit();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "You Selected" + p.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }

    }
});


//For scrolling issue use this
if(objects.get(position).isSelected)
       {
              cbBuy.setChecked(true);

       }
       else
       {
              cbBuy.setChecked(false);
       }

            return view;

        }

    }
```

Hope this will help u....if u have any questions u can ask

Comment: In my product class I already have a boolean called box, I have added the code above to show how it is in the product class.

Comment: Also setselected is coming up as Cannot resolve method setSelected

Comment: Any help with this please?

Comment: private boolean isSelected=false; just make getter and setter for this

Comment: Could you explain how to do the getter and setter please, im not sure how this is done?

Comment: public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

Comment: Great thats working,I just have one last question I tried putting in my sharedpreference to save the state when someone closing the application but it no longer seems to work. I have added to the new code

Comment: Where u r setting values in SharedPreferences? i can only see code for get SharedPreferences value

Comment: I believe its the line of settings.edit()putboolean(p.name, true).commit(); Thats how it was working before, with the code I had above, so not sure if I have to change the p.name or the object position to true/false?

Comment: I had done exactly that, I will try on my phone instead of the emulator once I get home. Thank You

Comment: Would I also have to commit the position?

Comment: I m not getting what u r telling?

Comment: So the state is not saving, even with the updated code. When I close the application and re open it the checkboxes that I ticked become un ticked, I want any boxes selected to save for the next time it opens.

Comment: I thought the fault was that the if statement is getting the objects location and the sharepreference is setting the p.name but I believe im wrong.

Comment: U can't save like this u have to store whole arraylist in shareprefrance....or with position

Comment: Im really sorry about all the confusion and comments, im trying to learn as I go along with this. How can I get it to save the state of the checked fields when the app is reloaded? How can I do what you said?

Comment: Done :) I really really appreciate your help with this

Comment: @77rshah My pleasure ...happy to help u

Comment: Are you able to see any faults as to why the sharedPreference isn't working correctly?

Comment: I'm unable to see the fault as products is being saved in an array?

Comment: I have created a new question on StackOverflow for this problem

Comment: send me that question link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274889/shared-preference-list-view-not-working-when-app-closed

Comment: It is the same code as this but thought it would be better to create a new question for it

Comment: Have you been able to see any faults in the code as to why its not saving or do you have another solution I could use?

Comment: your data is going to be same everytime? means product name and all

Comment: Products are the same but the checkedboxes arent saving, when I close the application and re open it, any product I have checked becomes unchecked